# Stutter-like movement with pathfinding implementation using A*

Tags: python, pygame, path-finding, a-star

I'm trying to develop a rudimentary RTS game and the pathfinding using a A* library is working fine. However the implementation is causing the character sprite to stutter or to get "teleported" backwards a bit when issued a new target location to path towards.

This turns into a big issue when issued continous calls during a short time.

The method I use is the `main`-loop feeds mouse-coordinates into the `User`-class and the `create_path()`-method. The create path uses an A* library called simply "pathfinding" to generate a list of path coordinates using a matrix.

Then the method `create_collision_rects()` creates small rect objects at the center of the coordinates of each path node.

Then the method `create_direction()` creates a vector from the `Unit`-object to the first instance of the pathfinding `rects`.

Every frame the method `path_collisions()` is run to check if the user has collided with the first `rect`in the series. If so remove `rect[0]` and `path[0]` and run `create_direction()` again.

So the pathfinding works as described, however as mentioned the big problem is that the `Unit`-object stutters backward when a new path is generated. This is a big problem when the path needs to be changed continously during a short time.

I've thought about this for quite some time now and haven't found any solution. Any help would be much appreciated!

`Code`

Runs once on user issuing a pathfinding command (eg. clicks on the screen):

```py
    #-----Create pathfinding-----
    def create_path(self, mouse_x, mouse_y):
        
            start_x, start_y = self.get_coord()
            start = self.grid.node(start_x, start_y)
            
            end_x, end_y = abs(mouse_x) // tile_size, abs(mouse_y) // tile_size
            end = self.grid.node(end_x,end_y) 

            self.path,_ = self.finder.find_path(start, end, self.grid)
            self.grid.cleanup()

            self.create_collision_rects()
```

Runs once after `create_path()`

```py
    #-----Create collision rects-----
    def create_collision_rects(self):        
        self.collision_rects = []

        for point in self.path:
            x = ((point[0] * tile_size) + tile_size//2)
            y = ((point[1] * tile_size) + tile_size//2)

            rect = pygame.Rect(((x - 4), (y - 4)), (8, 8))
            self.collision_rects.append(rect)

        self.get_direction()
```

Runs once after `create_collision_rects()`

```py
    #-----Create vector-----
    def get_direction(self):
        if self.collision_rects:
            start = pygame.math.Vector2(self.pos)
            end = pygame.math.Vector2(self.collision_rects[0].center)

            if start != end:
                self.direction = (end - start).normalize()
                
        else:
            self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0,0)
            self.path = []
```

Runs every frame in the `Unit`-class' `update()`-method

```py
    #-----Check path collisions-----
    def path_collisions(self):
        if self.collision_rects:
            if self.collision_rects[0].collidepoint(self.pos):

                self.pos = self.collision_rects[0].center
                self.collision_rects.pop(0)
                self.path.pop(0)

                self.get_direction()
        else:
            self.path = []
```

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer in another thread, answering this so that anyone else searching may find it:

[Implementing an A* algorithm with pygame I find my unit "back-tracks"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059861/implementing-an-a-algorithm-with-pygame-i-find-my-unit-back-tracks)

```
if unit is standing still
  compute pathfinding as you would normally do
else
  compute pathfinding from the unit cell
  discard the first cell of the pathfinding route (since it would backtrack)
  compute the route directly to the next cell (by drawing a correct path)
```